# MySQL REPLACE for combinations of keys instead of one key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE registration ( 
    `student_id` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    `course_id` INT(5) NOT NULL
)
```

Normally, a student can be able to register to multiple courses, like this:

```
------------------------------------------
|*    student_id   *|*     course_id    *|
------------------------------------------
|         1         |         3          |
------------------------------------------
|         1         |         4          |
------------------------------------------
|         1         |         17         |
------------------------------------------
|         2         |         2          |
------------------------------------------
|         2         |         37         |
------------------------------------------
```

I want to update the registrations of one student, with one query. using MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` or `REPLACE` for example.

Example: I want to update the courses the student with id 1 registered to, and put 3,4 and 18 instead of 3,4,17 in the course ids, in one query.

the problem is theses functions work for duplicate column, not for duplicate combination of columns.

In my table, student_ids and course_ids can repeat, be the combination of student_id and course_id can't. I want to use `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` or `REPLACE` with the combination of the columns.

any ideas?

Comment: Please explain a bit more to clarify

Comment: You can create a composite unique key `<student_id,course_id>`

Answer (score 0):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not actually fit for your use case.

I guess you need an update statement like below. Replace @newValue with your desired new value of `course_id`.

```
UPDATE registration
SET course_id = (CASE WHEN course_id = 3 THEN @newValue
                      WHEN course_id = 4 THEN @newValue
                      WHEN course_id = 17 THEN @newValue
                      ELSE course_id END )
WHERE student_id = 1 
AND course_id IN (3,4,17);
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for an atomic version of `DELETE FROM registration WHERE student_id = 1; INSERT INTO registration VALUES (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 17);`.